# magento 2.3.4 installtion stuck at 99% without error at Installing admin user

Tags: installation, magento2.3.4

magento 2.3.4 installtion stuck at 99% without error at Installing admin user

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Remove the partially installed database and create a new database. We can install Magento 2 by using the below Magento command. This is my favorite way of installation because it throws an error if any and we can check the progress.

```
bin/magento setup:install --base-url=http://local.ce231.com/ --db-host=127.0.0.1 --db-name=magento2 --db-user=magento --db-password=dbpassword --admin-firstname=Admin --admin-lastname=User --admin-email=your@mail.com --admin-user=username --admin-password=yourpassword --language=en_US --currency=USD --timezone=America/Chicago --use-rewrites=1
```

If you installed successfully, you can see the below success message.[image]

Easy for you reference: http://bilalusean.com/magento2-install-by-command-line/